# My CSS and Images do not seem to be working in Github?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

I am extremely new to the programming world and I understand that the best way to learn is to try and work things out myself, but this is something that I just can't seem to conquer so far. Locally, my CSS and HTML runs smoothly together, but when I posted it into Github, my website doesn't pull through the CSS file or my images file. I've pressed f12 and tried to change my file, but nothing seems to work. Any advice would be super as it is heartbreaking that I can't show my family what i've created so far, as im super happy with it.

Here is link to my repo if you wanted to check it out; https://github.com/Jamescoleman2020/jamescoleman2020.github.io

Comment: Try and switching to src="Images/mountain.png".

Comment: or change the Images directory name to images. If you are writing this on a mac they don't care about capitalization in file/path names. I bet Arundeep is on to something there.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for pointing out the error in the folder location with images. I changed the Images folder to images and changed the CSS folder to css in the hope this fixes it. I've made a whole new repo so just waiting to see if that fixed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @arundeepchohan thank you so much! Got it working, super appreciate the advice! :) Thanks!

Comment: and @FujiRoyale Thank you very much! Extremely helpful :D